# How to get the name of a variable as a string in a loop?

Tags: r, string, variables, names

I want to create a function to display some R variables' names properly.

I tried using `deparse(substitute(variable))` which works fine but I haven't been able to make it work inside a loop

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 7
myobjects = c(a, b, c)

for (i in 1:3){
  cat(deparse(substitute(myobjects [i])), " : ", myobjects [i], "\n")
}
```

which returns

```
myobjects[i]  :  5 
myobjects[i]  :  6 
myobjects[i]  :  7
```

instead of

```
a : 5
b : 6
c : 7
```

Comment: You may create a named object instead of `myobjects - c(a, b, c)` because the `myobjects` store only the value of the objects 'a', 'b', 'c'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'myobjects' contain only the values of the objects 'a', 'b', 'c'.  If we need to get the original objects, create a named `vector` and get the `names`

```
myobjects <- c(a = a, b = b, c = c)
for(i in 1:3) cat(names(myobjects[i]), " : ", myobjects[i], "\n")
#a  :  5 
#b  :  6 
#c  :  7
```

Or as @IceCreamToucan mentioned in the comments, it can be vectorized (without a `for` looop) as `paste` does vectorization

```
cat(paste0(names(myobjects), ' : ', myobjects), '\n', sep = '\n')
```

Comment: or `cat(paste0(names(myobjects), ' : ', myobjects), sep = '\n')`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Good advice, but be careful, your statement is missing a terminating `'\n'`, and **this will cause it not to print anything on some systems!** (E.g. mine.) Strings printed by `cat` *must* be terminated by newline.

Comment: Good to know. So it should be `cat(paste0(names(myobjects), ' : ', myobjects), '\n', sep = '\n')` instead then for portability?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Unfortunately, yes. I actually think this was a bug in R 3.5 on macOS which which was subsequently fixed (bug, because the behaviour is undocumented and inconsistent).